What does it mean that an abelian Category has functorial injective embeddings?
I found this definition on stack project

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. We say $\mathcal{A}$ has functorial injective embeddings if there exists a functor $$J:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow Arrows(\mathcal{A})$$ such that
(1) $s\circ J=id_{\mathcal{A}}$
(2) for any object $A\in Ob(\mathcal{A})$ the morphism $J(A)$ is injective.
(3) for any object $A\in Ob(\mathcal{A})$ the object $t(J(A))$ is an injective object of $\mathcal{A}$.

But it is not speicified what $s$ denotes in (1). I scrolled the chapter 12 but still could not find the definition for $s$. I guess $s$ means source and $t$ means target? And what does it mean that a morphism is injective? I guess monomorphism?

I believe that you are correct that $s$ stands for source and $t$ stands for target. So for example $s$ is a functor $\mathsf{Arrow}(\mathcal{A}) \to \mathcal{A}$ which on objects sends an arrow $f:x \to y$ to $x$ and on morphisms forgets to the first component.
You should also be correct in saying that injective morphism should mean monomorphism here.
What the definition really says is that for any object $a \in \mathcal{A}$ there exists an arrow $J(a) = (x \to y)$ such that

$x = a$, i.e. the arrow starts from $a$
the map is monic, i.e. an embedding
the target $y$ is injective

so we assign to $a$ an embedding into an injective object. Moreover, this is supposed to be done functorially, so we demand that $J$ is a functor.

Maybe you can also write down a diagram showing what it means to be a functor in this case.

@MartinBrandenburg Feel free to edit my answer. (This is just an excuse for: I'm really bad with diagrams on MSE ;-) )

Alright. See my answer then.

I would rather describe it via a special functor $I : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ and a natural transformation $\mathrm{id} \to I$.
More concretely, it means that for every object $A$ we have assigned a morphism $A \to I(A)$ such that

$A \to I(A)$ is a monomorphism,
$I(A)$ is injective.

Moreover, for every morphism $f : A \to B$ we have a morphism $I(f) : I(A) \to I(B)$ such that the diagram
$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> I(A) \\ @VVV @VVV \\ B @>>> I(B)
\end{CD}$
commutes. Also, $I(\mathrm{id}_A) = \mathrm{id}_{I(A)}$ and $I(g \circ f) = I(g) \circ I(f)$.
